# Extracting String From a variable Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have something like this stored in a variable after doing `''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))` to a parsed url and i have to fetch the school along with score and who it is playing with according to the argument given..some thing like `test.py "norfolk st."` should fetch the score like 'Norfolk St. 0-38 Rutgers' ...I tried using several functions like re.search(),string.find() and parsing through the characters which are not able to fetch the expected result? Need help

```
Norfolk St. 


0 - 38




    Rutgers 
    Final


     South Florida 


    6 - 21


     Michigan St. 
    Final


     Chowan 


    7 - 47


     Charlotte 
    Final


     SE Louisiana 


    17 - 38


     (24) TCU 
    Final


     W. Kentucky 


    20 - 52


     Tennessee 
    Final


     S. Carolina St. 


    13 - 52


     (4) Clemson 
    Final


     Middle Tenn. St. 


    20 - 40


     North Carolina 
    Final


     Central Conn. St. 


    44 - 51


     Lehigh 
    Final OT


     Army 


    14 - 40


     Ball St. 
    Final
```

The thing is I have to fetch the football box score from this url `http://sports.yahoo.com/college-football/scoreboard/?conf=all` and whehever user gives the school name in the command line argument it has to go to this URI checks the school name if there is a hyper link and it has to redirect and fetch the box score something like this

```
1   2   3   4   Total
FAU 3   3   0   7   13
ECU 7   14  10  0   31
```

if the game is going on the retrieved score should sleep for specified seconds and then retrieve latest score.So i am not sure which way I have to go ! Need help as I am new to python.

Comment: What is the pattern? I mean school, points(?), rival, etc. With a pattern maybe you can split them in an array and make easier the parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Is the structure [team 1] [score] [team 2] [notes about the game]? E.g. [team 1] = 'Norfolk St', [score] = '0-38', [team 2] = 'Rutgers', [notes about the game] = 'Final' in your original example?

And: Is your goal to enter a team on the command line to retrieve the records (both teams, and the score) of all the games they played in?

Assuming both those things: I'd first try tokenizing by line:

```
lines = your_string.split('\n').
clean_lines = [l.strip() for l in lines]
```

Then I'd build up a list of the actual games:

```
In [8]: games = [clean_lines[i:i+4] for i in xrange(0, len(clean_lines), 4)]

In [9]: games
Out[9]: 
[['Norfolk St.', '0 - 38', 'Rutgers', 'Final'],
 ['South Florida', '6 - 21', 'Michigan St.', 'Final'],
 ['Chowan', '7 - 47', 'Charlotte', 'Final'],
 ['SE Louisiana', '17 - 38', '(24) TCU', 'Final'],
 ['W. Kentucky', '20 - 52', 'Tennessee', 'Final'],
 ['S. Carolina St.', '13 - 52', '(4) Clemson', 'Final'],
 ['Middle Tenn. St.', '20 - 40', 'North Carolina', 'Final'],
 ['Central Conn. St.', '44 - 51', 'Lehigh', 'Final OT'],
 ['Army', '14 - 40', 'Ball St.', 'Final']]
```

If you want to look up all of the games in which a given team played, you can just iterate through the list of games and check if the string for the team appears in the 0 or 2 index. If you're going to be doing the lookup many times, though, it would be good to build a dictionary where the keys are the team names and the values are the indexes of the games in which they played.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks@sl8r000,The thing is I have to fetch the football box score from this url `http://sports.yahoo.com/college-football/scoreboard/?conf=all` and whehever user gives the school name in the command line argument it has to go to this URI checks the school name if there is a hyper link and it has to redirect and fetch the box score something like this
`1 2 3 4 Total`
`FAU 3 3 0 7 13`
`ECU 7 14 10 0 31 `                               if the game is going on the retrieved score should sleep for specified seconds and then retrieve latest score.So i am not sure which way I have to go ! Need help.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with regex. Based on the text, it looks like the string, minus whitespace, roughly follows and repeats this format:

```
thing 1
score
thing 2
"final"
```

As a result, I can go ahead, clean the string, iterate through it, and return each group of 4 as a part of a dictionary.

For example:

```
def chunk(iterable, n):
    '''chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2) -> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]'''
    return [iterable[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(iterable), n)]

def get_scores(raw):
    clean = [line.strip() for line in raw.split('\n') if line.strip() != '']
    return {thing1: (thing1, score, thing2) for (thing1, score, thing2, _) in chunk(clean, 4)}
```

Then, you could do:

```
>>> raw = ''.join(soup.findAll(text=True))
>>> scores = get_scores(raw)
>>> print scores['Norfolk St.']
('Norfolk St.', '0 - 38', 'Rutgers')
```

If you want the lookup to be case-insensitive, you could do:

```
def get_scores(raw):
    clean = [line.strip().lower() for line in raw.split('\n') if line.strip() != '']
    return {thing1: (thing1, score, thing2) for (thing1, score, thing2, _) in chunk(clean, 4)}
```

If you want to be able to look up either 'Norfolk St.' or 'Rutgers' and get the same result, you could do this:

```
def get_scores(raw):
    clean = [line.strip().lower() for line in raw.split('\n') if line.strip() != '']
    output = {}
    for (thing1, score, thing2, _) in chunk(clean, 4):
        data = (thing1, score, thing2)
        output[thing1] = data
        output[thing2] = data
    return output
```